# InvalidStructureException with error code 113 when sending proof using AMAX(aries-mobile-agent-xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, hyperledger-indy, aries

I am running Aries mobile agent based on aries-mobile-agent-xamarin. When sending proof using Xamarin Anroid emulator, I got InvalidStructureException with error code 113. It is coming from Indy SDK, anyone can shed light on how to enable Indy SDK Rust trace and display trace messages in Visual Studio Xamarin?

Comment: "When sending proof" - what does this mean?  Where is the relevant code that illustrates what you are doing?

Comment: Any SDK documentation to follow? And more details would be helpful.